# Facebook API to query my subscriptions/subscribers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, subscription

Do you know whether there's an API to query my subscribers and/or subscriptions?

Comment: Please elaborate on what work you've put into finding the answer yourself.

Comment: Maybe I'm just out of touch with FB, but what is a "subscriber" or "subscription" in that context?

Comment: @MattBall It's a new feature, much like an RSS feed of a user's updates. read more http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/09/14/facebook-allows-people-to-subscribe-to-friends/

Comment: why is this voted down? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @brc He's looking for a method to do it, you can't really document a negative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's undocumented, but it seems to be [/userId/subscribers](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/subscribers).  And you would need `user_subscriptions` extended permissions as shown below.  In fact, using the Graph API explorer is how I learned subscriptions were in fact available. I haven't found the subscriptions method yet, as /me/subscriptions is invalid as that is for applications and real-time update subscriptions.

Update: still undocumented, but it seems to be [/userId/subscribers](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/subscribers) and [/userId/subscribees](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/subscribees)

[image: user_subscriptions]

Comment: Needs more arrows. Definitely needs more arrows.

Comment: I'm trying to get access to subscriptions, too; anything new to report here? I noticed that the permission that Graph API Explorer is asking for is "Subscribers and Subscribees", but when I try /me/subscriptions with Explorer, it returns an "This method must be called with an app access_token", even though I provided one.  Maybe it's almost sorta kinda working?

Comment: @Jim Miller try /me/subscribers and /me/subscribees

Comment: can we do it with the scope ?

Answer (score 2):

Get subscriptions from the [`subscriptions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/subscription/) table with FQL:

```
SELECT subscribed_id FROM subscription WHERE subscriber_id = me()
```

Use FQL multiquery to get the subscription names as well:

```
query1: SELECT subscribed_id FROM subscription WHERE subscriber_id = me() 
query2: SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT subscribed_id FROM #query1)
```

You need the `user_subscriptions` permission for this query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will definitely try that!

Answer (score 0):

As OffBySome noted, you can get your own subscribers with the user_subscriptions permission (using me/subscribers), but not whom you are subscribed to, nor, more importantly any of the people's posts that you are subscribed to as they are not in your home feed. From experience, I would say that the Graph API is lagging behind the onslaught of new features. Normally it catches up after a few weeks.